# Getting over the Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

### The problem

I'm new to NextJS and TypeScript from React.JS and JavaScript background and discovering SSR and it's constraints, implementing some components to reuse them in multiple pages like this one:

```
export default function Slider({ className, title }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const swiperRef = useRef<SwiperCore>();

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <h3 className="pb-8 text-center font-primary text-xl md:text-left">
        {title}
      </h3>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
        <button onClick={() => swiperRef.current?.slidePrev()}>
          <Image
            src="/img/homepage/slider-skip.svg"
            alt="Previous button"
            height="48"
            width="48"
          />
        </button>
        <Swiper
          // install Swiper modules
          modules={[Navigation, A11y]}
          loop={true}
          spaceBetween={20}
          slidesPerView={3}
          breakpoints={{
            320: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
            },
            540: {
              slidesPerView: 2,
            },
            768: {
              slidesPerView: 3,
            },
            1100: {
              slidesPerView: 4,
            },
          }}
          onBeforeInit={(swiper) => {
            swiperRef.current = swiper;
          }}
          style={{ marginLeft: "1.3rem", marginRight: "1.3rem" }}
        >
          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className="relative h-44 w-full rounded-md bg-primary-400">
              <p className="absolute bottom-4 left-4 font-primary text-base font-semibold text-white">
                Let's make up
              </p>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>

          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className="relative h-44 w-full rounded-md bg-primary-400">
              <p className="absolute bottom-4 left-4 font-primary text-base font-semibold text-white">
                Let's make up
              </p>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>

          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className="relative h-44 w-full rounded-md bg-primary-400">
              <p className="absolute bottom-4 left-4 font-primary text-base font-semibold text-white">
                Let's make up
              </p>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>

          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className="relative h-44 w-full rounded-md bg-primary-400">
              <p className="absolute bottom-4 left-4 font-primary text-base font-semibold text-white">
                Let's make up
              </p>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        </Swiper>
        <button onClick={() => swiperRef.current?.slideNext()}>
          <Image
            src="/img/homepage/slider-skip.svg"
            alt="Previous button"
            height="48"
            width="48"
            className="scale-x-[-1]"
          />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And start to get these kind of errors:
[image: ded]

### Possible solution

I know that by doing SSR, the pages are rendered in HTML, which is not the case for my components that run on the client side, but after some research, I discovered that it was possible to avoid these errors by using the `next/dynamic` package, and that now I will have to import these kind of dynamic packages with this method:

```
const Slider = dynamic(() => import("../components/homepage/slider"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

### My concern

Everything seems to work perfectly but takes time to load (delay), per example, my navbar is using dynamic data and can potentially be affected by these errors and using the `next/dynamic` package, it will take a while to display and this makes me embarrassed as the navigation should be the first thing to display, does anyone have a solution to avoid this delay and its constraints?